# Ajax method post and url does not work to change my database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm learning to use ajax. I'm facing problems while fixing the issues because there is no error notifications like PHP or MySQL.
Till now, I have learn how to manipulate Database using CURD. Everything went well but MySQL itself still do nothing in this part. Please give me some idea, because I don't know what's the problem with this. I think I have not made any mistake.

```
$("#prodButton").on('click', function(){
    if (jamStock< jamReq || fruitsStock< fruitsReq || sugarStock< sugarReq){
        alert("ingredients is not enough");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "production.php",
            data: {
                jam: jamStock- jamReq,
                fruits: fruitsStock- fruitsReq,
                sugar: sugarStock - sugarReq,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Data has been changed");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

oh well about the production.php:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
if (isset($_POST['jam'])) {
    $sql = "UPDATE ingre SET
         jam =" . $_POST['jam'] . "
        , fruits =" . $_POST['fruits'] . "
        , sugar=" . $_POST['sugar'] . "
         WHERE 1";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
} else {
    die("browser unable to load");
}
?>
```

Comment: please add the PHP code.

Comment: @AfaanBilal ya i forgot about that, just edited.

Comment: try this mysqli_query($con, $sql)

Comment: "UPDATE `ingre` SET
         `jam` =" . $_POST['jam'] . "
        , `fruits` =" . $_POST['fruits'] . "
        , `sugar`=" . $_POST['sugar'] . "  WHERE 1";

Comment: @sudhakar im using PHP 5.3 and mysql is not deprecated, and yes i'm using mysql. it's not an issue because i'm still learning ajax, and mysql is much faster to type than pdo or mysqli.

Comment: ok, let me check give me some time

Comment: You should learn to use secure programming from the very start. Please use prepared statements and *never* directly put your input un-sanitized into an SQL query.

Comment: @AfaanBilal
i usually using this as my security  >>>>>> function array_sanitize(&$item){
 $item = htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($item)));
 } <<<<<<< and this >>>>>>function sanitize($data){
 return  htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
 } <<<<<<

Comment: in production.php which part is reflect in result ?
if OR Else ?

Comment: @maulik i'm sorry i'm don't get you. but i guess, i have no result statement in there. The result is in the index.php after url:production.php?

Comment: did you get any error in console ?

Comment: @JYoThI no no, not at all. that's why i asks in here, i don't know what is my mistake.

Comment: did you noticed that you missed `single` quotes in this line `include connect.php';`

Comment: @JYoThI hahaha sorry sorry, i was change my file name, because to connect it is using my name. LoL

Comment: `mysql_*`  is deprecated use `mysqli_* or pdo`

Comment: @JYoThI
im using PHP 5.3 and in that php version, mysql is not deprecated, and yes i'm using mysql. it's not an issue because i'm still learning ajax, and mysql is much faster to type than pdo or mysqli.

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Comment: @JYoThI not yet, but if u want me to try to convince me about mysql. i can doing query in phpmyadmin using mysql.

Comment: For testing purpose change all your code into respectively `GET` method and call the file directly in browser with `query string parameters` and make sure that your `php code` is fine or not

Comment: in first place echo "check"; exit(); before & after include 'connect.php';
So you get notify is all ok on your include 'connect.php' file.!

Comment: @JYoThI which is the method under ajax too, change to GET?

Comment: @maulik i just did that and it's not echoing, nothing to display, it just get back to my index file do nothing like before.

Comment: it means issue is in your url: "production.php" ...
your file is yet not call for ajax.

set ABSPATH in URL .

Comment: Don't touch those ajax part . simple change your `PHP code` and call the file directly in browser like this `localhost/folder/file.php?jam=valu&fruits=value&sugar=value`

Comment: @JYoThI all of the ingredients, with their values on database?

Comment: or add error handling part in ajax like this `success: function(data) {
                alert("Data has been changed");
                location.reload();
            }, error : function(xhr,error_string,error_r){  console.log(error_string); console.log(error_r); }`

Comment: @JYoThI i did ur error handling and shows nothing.

Comment: are you sure looking in browser console tab . ?

Comment: @JYoThI i'm using chrome and i do right click inspect or f12 to open the console, is that right?

Comment: yeah your right . Then we will debug it add alert in else part `if (jamStock< jamReq || fruitsStock< fruitsReq || sugarStock< sugarReq){
        alert("ingredients is not enough");
    } else { alert('coming to else part'); ...  }`

Comment: @JYoThI, ya the alert shows up.  and ?

Answer (score 0):

-when you write query for insert or update record in table its important to use these signs for name of columns `, and its important for string values ( like varchar, char, dates, text..) to use single quotes [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

```
$sql = "UPDATE `ingre` 
      SET
     `jam` ='{ $_POST['jam']}', `fruits` = '{$_POST['fruits']}', sugar='{$_POST['sugar']}' WHERE 1";
```

-when using ajax its important to return something (catch in success and chech what happend) to controle success or fail ajax

-and one more thing, I use this "form" for ajax to control response

```
$.ajax({

    url: ,
    method: '',
    data: {

    }
}).done(function (data) {

}).fail(function () {

}).always(function () {

});
});
```

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Notice the quotes around the values.

Comment: Please add some text to your answer which shows why they should try your answer and what is different which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add alert(data); in script & echo in php file & check what you get in response alert message.

```js
$("#prodButton").on('click', function(){
    if (jamStock< jamReq || fruitsStock< fruitsReq || sugarStock< sugarReq){
        alert("ingredients is not enough");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "production.php",
            data: {
                jam: jamStock- jamReq,
                fruits: fruitsStock- fruitsReq,
                sugar: sugarStock - sugarReq,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                alert("Data has been changed");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

```html
<?php
include 'connect.php';
echo "connection working<br>";
if (isset($_POST['jam'])) {
  echo "True<br>";
    $sql = "UPDATE ingre SET
         jam =" . $_POST['jam'] . "
        , fruits =" . $_POST['fruits'] . "
        , sugar=" . $_POST['sugar'] . "
         WHERE 1";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
} else {
  echo "False<br>";
    die("browser unable to load");
}
?>
```

Comment: it didn't work, and i just get back to index.php without any change or error notification.